# Extra clickable space after anchor closes

Tags: html, css

With this code:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/"> <mark></mark> </a>
```

A working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WM8A5/104/

With this piece of code an extra `_` character appears. But if you use styling and take away text decoration it simply makes it invisible. 
Oddly enough it only happens when there is text right after the anchor tag is closed.

Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: _ character is linking to your website here..Tell us why did you need empty <mark></mark>?

Comment: At first I thought mark was apart of the problem. And I saw the problem when I was using a "mark" inside of the anchor tag. --That's not my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between `</mark>` and `</a>`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WM8A5/110/)

Comment: I realized that moments before you posted, but thanks!

Comment: Yeah I see your own answer.. I was too slow! Glad you fixed your problem though :)